# Oozie coordinator done flag with variable in uri-template

Tags: oozie, hue, oozie-coordinator

I need a done flag with variable in uri. 
According to documentation: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a5.1._Synchronous_Datasets it is possible.

My uri looks like

```
<uri-template>
  hdfs://foo:9000/app/logs/${YEAR}${MONTH}/${DAY}/${hour_int}
</uri-template>
```

and I defined ${hour_int} variable in Advanced settings/Workflow properties.

I get error:

```
E1004: Expression language evaluation error, Unable to evaluate :hdfs://foo:9000/app/logs/${YEAR}${MONTH}/${DAY}/${hour_int}:
```

Need help on where am going wrong ...

Comment: "Advanced setting" - you mean you are using HUE??? From personal experience, every time you try non-trivial settings, HUE produces a scrambled XML that is either syntaxically wrong or functionnaly wrong.

Comment: "Workflow properties" - bad idea; you should try to hover your mouse over "Oozie parameters instead", in case you see the magic **market** example keyword...

Comment: Yes, I'm using HUE :/

Comment: Are you trying to specify an input URI or just the done flag? I tried both and it works. Btw the Oozie editor was completed revamped 6 months ago: http://gethue.com/new-apache-oozie-workflow-coordinator-bundle-editors/

Comment: @Romain, Uri for done flag. I have version of Hue 3.7.0 and it doesn't :/